# Find pointer to the Instruction that assigns to value in LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

Suppose I have a pointer to some Value* val in LLVM. I want to get a pointer to Instruction that assigned value to the variable that val points to. How can I do it?
This is an example of code

```
%add = add nsw i32 %aa, %bb
%div = sdiv i32 %add, %cc
```

I have a pointer to variable `add` and I want to get a pointer to the Instruction that assigned to variable add, which is pointer to `%add = add nsw i32 %aa, %bb` instruction

So far the only thing I found was a pointer to Basicblock that the variable belongs to. This is how I did it

```
Instruction * tmpI = dyn_cast<Instruction>(val);
BasicBlock * b = tmpI->getParent();
```

Comment: The LLVM-IR is a Static-Single-Assignment Intermediate Representation. The pointer to the instruction IS the pointer to the assignment. The add instruction and the assignment to the add register have a one-to-one matching since registers can only be assigned once, and instructions can only assign to a single register.

Comment: Just in case I misunderstood your question. If what you really wanted was the pointer to the instruction in your the lowered binary that assigned to `%add`, today, without modifying LLVM, you can't (easily) do that. If you intend to go this route, you could rely on debug-information to do something similar.

Comment: I am trying to get the Instruction that assigned to the variable from the variable itself, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand, you want to get the `llvm::Instruction` that does the addition? If that's the case, see my first comment. In your code example. if the variable `val` points to the register `%add`. It happens that `val` points to an `llvm::Instruction` (which inherits from `llvm::Value`). And this instruction is the addition you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I wanted. My code works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer was [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927170/find-pointer-to-the-instruction-that-assigns-to-value-in-llvm#comment132226147_74927170) in the comments by [jmmartinez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032949/jmmartinez):

> The LLVM-IR is a Static-Single-Assignment Intermediate Representation. The pointer to the instruction IS the pointer to the assignment. The add instruction and the assignment to the add register have a one-to-one matching since registers can only be assigned once, and instructions can only assign to a single register.

> [...] In your code example. if the variable `val` points to the register `%add`. It happens that `val` points to an `llvm::Instruction` (which inherits from `llvm::Value`). And this instruction is the addition you're looking for.

To add a bit more detail, the LLVM [`Value`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Value.html) type is a base class of the LLVM [`Instruction`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html) type. For IR values like `%add` in the example, the IR allocates a specific `Instruction` subtype, [`BinaryOperator`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1BinaryOperator.html) in the case of an `add` instruction. So the pointer to a `Value` for `%add` is actually a pointer to the same object as the instruction, just using its base class.

LLVM also has a special system for casting these pointers between types in the IR type hierarchy: https://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates

Here are some example functions that take a specific `llvm::Value` and return the `llvm::Instruction` that produces that value:

```cpp
#include <llvm/IR/Value.h>
#include <llvm/IR/Instruction.h>

using llvm::Value;
using llvm::Instruction;
using llvm::cast;
using llvm::dyn_cast;
using llvm::dyn_cast_or_null;
using llvm::isa;

// Either convert a `Value` to an `Instruction`
// or return null.
auto tryGetInstr(Value* value) -> Instruction* {
  return dyn_cast<Instruction>(value);
}

// Just test whether a value was computed with an
// `Instruction` without converting it. Don't use
// this if you'll just end up converting it, use
// the above that combines the two.
auto isInstr(Value* value) -> Instruction* {
  return isa<Instruction>(value);
}

// When you already know the value *must* be computed
// by an instruction, you can assert this and convert
// it in a way that will never produce a null.
auto getInstr(Value* value) -> Instruction* {
  return cast<Instruction>(value);
}

// If `value` is non-null, try to convert it to an
// `Instruction`. Returns null if `value` is null
// or it isn't referencing an `Instruction`.
auto tryGetInstrIfNonNull(Value* value) -> Instruction* {
  return dyn_cast_or_null<Instruction>(value);
}
```

https://cpp.compiler-explorer.com/z/f13bT4vb5