# How to get the variable, which the value is assigned to, in an instruction in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

For example,

If I want to store and save the variables %1, and % 3 in the instruction

%1 = alloca i32, align 4

%3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4

into " *Value " variable for further use, how can I get them?

It looks like getOperand() can only get the operands, but not the variables being assigned.

It looks like getOperand() can only get the operands, but not the variables being assigned.

Comment: Hello hahastof. I think your question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74927170/find-pointer-to-the-instruction-that-assigns-to-value-in-llvm#comment132232200_74927170 .

Comment: It sounds as if you want the debug info? If that's correct: Debug info is quite complex, because source languages are very different, but some of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bllvm%5D+debug+info) should help you. It may be helpful to solve a simpler problem first to get used to this subsystem, perhaps finding the line number of the allocation.